# Include issue in a resource script (.rc)

Tags: c++, mfc

Ive made a project (copied actually, but its from an old project hugely out of date that doesnt compile anymore). Its a MFC project. In the .rc file there is an include to two files that are also used in the normal code itself. The problem is that when i compile, in the .rc file I get an error returned saying it cant find either file.

The .rc file and the main project are in different folders but the number of folders is the same. So the directory structure is:

```
ManagerDir->ManagerProj
ManagerDir->ManagerProj.rc
```

In my additional dependencies i have a path to the folder where the files it cant find are. That works for the project code. In the .rc file if i give the long, ..\..\Dir1\subDir\.., path the include works. The problem is that the same thing is happening with further includes so this seems to be a symptom and not the problem.

I tried moving the rc script from where it is now to put it in the same folder as the project code but it re-writes the rc script when i do this.

Anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: The directories searched by rc.exe is a separate project setting.  In recent versions of VS, that's set by Project + Properties, Resources, General, Additional Include Directories setting.

Comment: Thanks. That was doing my nut in.